# I want to replace the word "Ballarini pentola" in paragraph from the list on most left-side

Tags: excel, vba

[i want to replace the word "Ballarini pentola" in a paragraph in each Row with the list of words provided in separate column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSAAh.png)

Comment: You need to try to write some code, and we'll help you when you're stuck.

Comment: You just need to perform a `replace` operation for each row.  This is something you can do with a VBA Macro.  Assuming you are not familiar with vba, I will show you the way to start it: You can record a macro (pls google if your dont know how to do it) for a couple of replace operations.  Then stop your macro and analyse the codes (to see the codes hit Alt + F8, and then click edit). Try to understand the logic. Then do a quick search of `do while` and `loop` vba commands and then edit / enhance your code to perform replace operations for all rows. Let us know if you need help on the way.

Comment: Basbadger's answer below is way better and easy solution to your problem.  Pls accept his/her answer by clicking the tick button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first cell is A1, `=SUBSTITUTE(C1,B1,A1)` should work for you.